# layered png image using a PHP library

Tags: php, image, png

Does anyone know about a PHP library which can produce layered PNG images? (I'm not sure, but I think that tiff image standard supports layers also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org) [API site](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php):

> PHP
>   MagickWand for PHP a native PHP-extension to the ImageMagick MagickWand API.
>   IMagick is a native PHP extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API.  Documentation for the extension is available here.
>   phMagick is a wrapper class for ImageMagick, wrapping the most common web image manipulation actions in easy to use functions, but allowing full access to ImageMagick's power by issuing system calls to it's command-line programs.
>
> ImageMagick® is a software suite to create, edit, and compose bitmap images. It can read, convert and write images in a variety of formats (over 100) including DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF. Use ImageMagick to translate, flip, mirror, rotate, scale, shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bézier curves.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR, PNG does not support layers. MNG does and you can produce these with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). 
 For PHP extension see: http://www.php.net/imagick

Comment: I think he means with backgrounds?

Comment: yeah, but then I don't see where the problem is. GD supports that without any problems.

Comment: Fireworks uses a layered file with a PNG extension, I imagine he means that.

Comment: Then that's some Adobe proprietary extension.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the layered PNG files as per fireworks, I don't think you can do it. I've not seen anything except fireworks that supports these files properly.

Comment: The extra information in a Fireworks PNG is contained in private ancillary chunks and I believe the format of these chunks has not been made public.